# Display Default image when there is no image in database inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am using generic handler to display database  images in gridview. It's working fine. But, I want to check if there is no image for specific ID, if so I want to display a default image.

This what i am using inside  gridview :

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ImID=" + Eval("UPCCode")%>'       class="photo" height="160" width="160"   CommandName="ItemDetail" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ItemDescription")%>'/>
```

Please suggest what I have to do for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function and pass Eval("UPCCode") as a parameter to the function and check.

```
ImageUrl='<%#ImagePath( "ImageHandler.ashx?ImID=" +Eval("UPCCode").ToString(),Eval("Image").ToString())%>' >
```

And in code behind

```
protected string ImagePath(string tableCodeUrl,string imageColumnValue)
{
    string url=string.empty;

    if(imageColumnValue=="")
        url="defaultImagePath"; // Give path to default image

    else
        url = tableCodeUrl;

    return url;
}
```

Comment: @mhsaan can you please show me some code.i am new  to .net.     thanks

Comment: @mhsaan no you are wrong.UPCCode  is id   of table.it's not null.Null value  is in Image  column.Like if UPCCode=1 and Image="abc"  its  working.but if UPCCode=555  and Image="Null" then i want to diplay default image.

Comment: So you have a column named "Image" ...?

Comment: use isnull([Image],"") to change null value to blank value in your SQL ....and check edited answer ..